# Location of Gearman Workers

Tags: php, yii2, gearman

I have Yii2 frontend server and gearman server.
For Yii2 i use filsh/yii2-gearman

Where I have to locate Workers code?
On Frontend server? Or I have to install Yii basic app on gearman server and locate worker code on it?